# WPF TextBlock Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I have create textblocks in my grid in my wpf application. I know how to create the click event. But I'm not sure how to get properties from that cell. The properties I want Grid.Row and Grid.Column. How can I do this?

```
<Window x:Class="TicTacToe.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Tic-Tac-Toe" Height="356" Width="475">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" ShowGridLines="True" Height="313" Margin="10,10,2,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="o" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Lucida Bright" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MouseLeftButtonDown="ChoosePosition" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" ></TextBlock>

    </Grid>

</Window>

 private void ChoosePosition(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: you have to put you textblox within the column/row in your grid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Grid.Row and Grid.Column are attached properties from the Grid class, you can get them using this syntax:

```
int row = Grid.GetRow(myTextBox);
int column = Grid.GetColumn(myTextBox);
```

In your case, you can cast the sender argument in the Click handler, so it would look like this:

```
var myTextBox = sender as TextBox;
if(myTextBox != null) {
   int row = Grid.GetRow(myTextBox);
   int column = Grid.GetColumn(myTextBox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `sender` parameter? That will give you a  reference to the  textbox object which might be all you need depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just change TextBox to TextBlock